# PHP redirect on extjs form submission

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I have an extjs formPanel for the login process, with

> standartSumbit: false
>   ...
>   loginForm.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'index_files/login.php'; 
>   loginForm.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
>   loginForm.getForm().submit();

login.php contains:

> if ( $name == '1')  { header("Location: http://www.google.com/");   exit;  }

But instead of redirecting I'm getting from chrome debugger

> Failed to load resource www.google.com

What is the problem?

thank you.

ps: i can't use GET

Comment: Is this the first thing that happens? E.g. nothing is printed before it, etc.?

Comment: it is the first thing that happens. (that i can see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success function of the extjs, try

```
 success:function(){ 
                      var redirect = 'http://www.google.com'; 
                      window.location = redirect;
                  },
```

Comment: thank you, your answer was very helpful, though, is there a way to do it via php only?